# How to get facebook friends without facebook login token?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making an app where i have logged in user from facebook graph api and than saved his facebook id to my own database. Now i have give user another option where he can login with google account. When the user logged in with google than i fetched his facebook id from my database(Which i saved earlier) and want to get his friends (Who have accessed the app) and now at the time of login via google i dont have facebook login token.
**I want to get his facebook friends who have used the app with only facebook id without facebook login Token.** 
How can i do it? 
Can we get friend list without Token?

I have already got permission from user to access his friend list earlier when user logged in from facebook.
Thank You in advance...

Comment: Save the Facebook access token when the logged in using Facebook. And then use that token to get friends. There is no other way.

Comment: But if the login token expired than @WizKid

Comment: Then you have to get a new one

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension